# Rounding/formatting decimals using pandas, reading from columns of a csv file

Tags: pandas, csv, formatting, rounding

Need to read a csv file and have it output the min, max, range, and standard deviation for each of the 3 columns in the file. This isn't the problem I'm having. What I'm having trouble with is something that I feel like should be relatively simple, getting the outputs to round to 2 decimal places. While it's not really necessary as the program does what it needs to do, it would be great if it could be formatted that way for the sake of presentation

I approached this problem using pandas, calculating the four parts of the problem was easy but I cannot, for the life of me, find out how to round any of the decimals. I've tried .round() and various other lines of code but I still wind up at a dead end

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Exam-Data-Dstat.csv')



col_name =df.columns[0]
df=df.rename(columns = {col_name:'Ease'})



col_name =df.columns[1]
df=df.rename(columns = {col_name:'Useful'})

col_name =df.columns[2]
df=df.rename(columns = {col_name:'Intent'})


print("Min, Max, Range, Mean, and SD of Ease: ")
print (df.Ease.min())

print (df.Ease.max())

print (df.Ease.max() - df.Ease.min()) 

print (df.Ease.mean())

print (df.Ease.std())

print("\n")

print("Min, Max, Range, Mean, and SD of Useful: ")
print (df.Useful.min())

print (df.Useful.max())

print (df.Useful.max() - df.Useful.min())

print (df.Useful.mean())

print (df.Useful.std())

print("\n")

print("Min, Max, Range, Mean, and SD of Intent: ")
print (df.Intent.min())

print (df.Intent.max())

print (df.Intent.max() - df.Intent.min())

print (df.Intent.mean())

print (df.Intent.std())
```

Like I said, everything the is already being displayed when this is ran in the terminal should come out rounded to 2 decimal places, that is the only thing I really need help with. I'm fairly new at Python and have only had a few months experience

Comment: use `round` which is in the python standard library

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to format the output for the print function, not actually the dataframe values.

So, you can format the output like this:

```
print("%.2f" % df.Ease.min())
```

the `"%.2f"` indicates you want to print 2 digits after the dot for a float type value

Answer (score 0):

You can use pythons inbuilt **round function**.

```
print(round(df.Useful.mean(), 2))
```

2 means you want to print 2 digits after the dot.